# Docker, FastAPI, and Python Import Issue

Tags: python, docker, fastapi

My directory structure:

```
.
|--app
|   |--__init__.py
|   |--main.py
|   |--module_1.py
|   |--module_2.py
|  
|--Dockerfile
|--requirements.txt
```

Inside `main.py` import `module_1.py` like this: `from . import module_1`

It works fine. But inside `module_2` when I try `from . import module_1` I get `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

What gives? I tried writing the following into `__init__.py` to see if it would help, but it didn't:

```
from app import main
from app import module_1
from app import module_2
```

And then in `module_2` I tried both the former line and simply `import module_1` but the same error occurs with the former line and the `ModuleNotFoundError` occurs with the latter.

Comment: How are you running the application; what directory are you starting in?  This looks like it might be in a Docker context, does it behave differently in a container vs. a virtual environment?

Comment: I'm starting to think that maybe relative and absolute imports are just broken in Python3.10.0 on Windows 11, since I have now tested with a very simple setup (search relative imports realpython) and it simply doesn't work inside or outside of Docker.

Comment: After a lot of digging and looking at and following exactly Python's documentation it appears that pathing is just broken for some people and has been for a long time.

Answer (score 3):

When you nest your module with the relative import 1 level deeper, you don't get the error because you have a *known parent package*.

```
app/
├── __init__.py
├── main.py
└── modules
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── module1.py
    └── module2.py
```

A simplified Dockerfile might look this this.

```
FROM python
WORKDIR /app
COPY app .
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

Sometimes, although not required in this case, it can also make sense to set the [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH).

```
ENV PYTHONPATH=/app
```

Comment: Your suggestion allows one of the modules in modules dir to see another module, but adding a third module in the same dir, it won't be seen by anything. There's no question that absolute and relative pathing simply do not work the way described in Python's official docs. I've followed it exactly. And it's also obvious that this has been a problem for a long time and not just maybe 3.10.0 and Win11 like I thought.

Comment: +1 for the `ENV PYTHONPATH=/app`. It solved my prob which was, app was not recognized as a python package or root